# Javascript - concat() acts like push()

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have multiple byte arrays with a length of 10000000 each (10MB). I store them in this object

```
class object{
    var buffer = new Array();
    updateBuffer(buffer){
        this.buffer = this.buffer.concat(buffer);
    }
}
```

I call the method every time I receive a new byte array (~15 times). I would expect the result of `object.buffer.length` to be ~150MB but instead the output is 15. If I try to do something like this `object.buffer[0].lenght` the output is 10MB, so `concat()` is acting as a `push()`. Do you know why?

Comment: I think you should verify that those `buffer` objects really look the way you think they look. What you've described would make sense if each one is an array nested inside another array.

Comment: The code you provided isn't valid javascript. https://jsfiddle.net/4rjm5g0k/

Comment: @Pointy Yeah you are right it would make more sense but they are actually arrays. Just verified it by using `buffer.length` (10MB). @Olian04 it is, you just haven't created an instance for that object

Answer (score 0):

I think you create an instance of `object` class per time that you have received a new package! Because this, per time، a new object and thus a new `buffer` array is created.

You must create an instance of `object` outside of your timer (receiver) block and use it after receiving per pack.

---

**Also**, check your `buffer` parameter with console(`console.log(buffer)`) or other ways. This is possible that it be like `[[byte1,b2,b3]]` instead of `[byte1,b2,b3]` and this leads to length=15.

Comment: It actually creates a matrix, as I said it behaves like an array.push would. It's not a problem of multiple instances because this problem happens even with the first package received. The matrix looks like this: `[[10MB], [10MB], [10MB]]`, while I should have an array like: `[150MB]`

Comment: This problem is described in the 2nd part of my answer. If the `buffer` parameter be like `[[b1,b2,...]]`, then the result will be: `[[..],[..],[..],...]` and thus the length will be equal to 15 (similar `push`). In this case, you can change your code like this: `this.buffer = this.buffer.concat.apply(this.buffer, buffer)`